# What Does the "?" Symbol Mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, properties, setter, getter

I am learning Objective C for ios programming and ran into the following line of code in the 
getter method of a property of a card called suit:

```
-(NSString *)suit 
{
     return _suit ? _suit: @"?";
}
```

This is supposed to return "?" if the suit is nil but I'm not sure how this line works. What does the ? in "return _suit ?..." mean? How does this code function and how is it interpreted by the computer?

Answer (score 1):

That's the ternary operator. You can search the site to find out more.

Basically it means "if".

If `_suit` is not `nil`, return `_suit`, otherwise return `@"?"`. (the "otherwise" is after the colon).

Answer (score 0):

It it s [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C) it is a short form of

```
if(_suit) {
   return _suit;
} else {
   return @"?";
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: The ternary operator does not cause the function to return. It's only equivalent to that when used in a return statement.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I was restating the expression: return _suit ? _suit: @"?";

Answer (score 0):

? Is ternary operator which work very similar to if()...else...

```
(condition)?<value if true>:<value if false>
```

Read following:

[Objective-C Tricks: #1 Ternary Operations](http://toastmo.com/blog/2012/10/24/objective-c-tricks-number-1-ternary-operations/)
[Objective-C ternary operator](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/objective-c-ternary-operator/)